# JSON data to columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the form of a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
A      B                               C
ab     {"app":"x","wid":10,"a42":5}    e
y      {"hair":"x","wid":10,"a42":2}   r
```

and I want to convert my dataframe like this:

```
A    C    app    wid    a42    hair
ab   e    x      10     5      -
y    r    -      10     2      r
```

These questions were not helpful:

[JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe) 
[Convert Json data to Python DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616695/convert-json-data-to-python-dataframe) 
[How to convert a parsed json file to pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626013/how-to-convert-a-parsed-json-file-to-pandas-data-frame) 
 

And I have also seen many other links but stuck with this problem.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns/38233518#38233518

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [143]: df.B.apply(pd.Series)
Out[143]:
   a42  app hair  wid
0    5    x  NaN   10
1    2  NaN    x   10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ab','y'],
                   'B':[{"app":"x","wid":10,"a42":5},{"hair":"x","wid":10,"a42":2}],
                   'C':['e','r']})
print (df)
    A                                   B  C
0  ab   {'a42': 5, 'wid': 10, 'app': 'x'}  e
1   y  {'a42': 2, 'wid': 10, 'hair': 'x'}  r

print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.B))
   a42  app hair  wid
0    5    x  NaN   10
1    2  NaN    x   10

print (pd.concat([df[['A','C']], pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.B)], axis=1))
    A  C  a42  app hair  wid
0  ab  e    5    x  NaN   10
1   y  r    2  NaN    x   10
```

Comment: I don't have data in this form : {'A':['ab','y'],
                     'B':[{"app":"x","wid":10,"a42":5},{"hair":"x","wid":10,"a42":2}],
                     'C':['e','r']}. I have it in the form of dataframe and when I am doing the process  "pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.B)" result comes wrong.

Comment: yes, I know. You have data in form `df`, right? I add creating df for better testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)) )
or 
df["B"] = df["B"].map(eval)

df2 = df["B"].apply(pd.Series )
result = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).drop('B', axis=1)
```

Comment: If this answer helped, please upvote and correct if it is.